# Automatically create child custom post when creating a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called ‘artist’. Whenever I create an ‘artist’ post I get the following permalink:
www.myexample.com/artist/artist-name

This is my single-artist.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=artist' ); ?>
      <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="artist-info">
            <p>Artist name</p>
            <a href="/hire-artist/artist-name">Hire artist</a>
        <div>
      <?php endwhile ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is the code to register the custom post:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    register_post_type( 'artist',
      array(
        'public' => true,
        'label'  => 'Artists',
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
      )
    ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

I want to do that when an ‘artist’ post is created then also a ‘subpost’ of it is created using this permalink:
www.myexample.com/hire-artist/artist-name

So both post remains associated but are different custom post type since I’ll be using another template for the ‘hire-artist’ sub post. Also the link in the `a` tag gets the link to the child custom post.

Is it possible to do? What would be the best way to do this automation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than create another post which appears to be for the sole purpose of rendering a different template, I would [add a rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to support an additional segment at the end of artist URLs. In this case, your URLs will be:

> www.example.com/artist/artist-name/hire/

The advantage of this is that all data pertaining to an artist can remain within the single artist post. When these posts are rendered on the front end, the queried object contains the artist data, no connection of multiple posts is necessary.

To accomplish this, we first add the endpoint:

```
function wpd_hire_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'hire', EP_PERMALINK );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_hire_endpoint' );
```

Note that if your post type is hierarchical, you'll need to use the `EP_PAGES` endpoint mask instead of `EP_PERMALINK`.

Next, add a filter to `single_template` to load the hire template when those URLs are visited:

```
function wpd_hire_template( $template = '' ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if( ! array_key_exists( 'hire', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) return $template;

    $template = locate_template( 'hire.php' );
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpd_hire_template' );
```

Remember to flush rewrite rules after adding the endpoint.

EDIT- adding an additional rewrite rule to achieve alternate URL structure:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'hire-artist/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?artist=$matches[1]&hire=true',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: Thanks Milo! it's just the client asked to do this way, with this permalink for SEO purposes. I will try this code but can you help me with an alternative to do the way I need to? thanks :)

Comment: Maybe someone else can help. The other way is far more complicated and I don't have the time or energy to write all that code :)

Comment: Well not all the code but just what would be the way to do it I mean. So I have a reference to try, it's just I don't know where to start :/

Comment: I would just do it this way and [add a rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to support the other URL structure. But I'd have to see evidence that you actually gain anything from an SEO perspective.

Comment: +1 for keeping everything in one post, URL is just an implementation detail (though might be tad nasty to get right for custom requirements).

Comment: @milo haha I'll ask the evidence to the client. Thanks I'll let you know if I use your code ;)

Comment: @wpuser - see edit above for rewrite rule which gives you your URL structure and manually sets the `hire` endpoint query var. the other code would remain the same. rewrite rules should be added on `init` action.